# Perfect + SQLiteStORM, how to multiple insert

Tags: swift, sqlite, perfect

I'm using `perfect` with [SQLite](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-SQLite) driver and [StORM](https://github.com/SwiftORM/SQLite-StORM) as connector. I can save (create) multiple rows one by one. To make it faster, I'd like to create multiple rows at once, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the source code for perfect `SQLite-StORM` and `Perfect-SQLite` - currently there seems to be no logic to handle multiple rows insert statements. Tossing raw statements like this seems to be the only way with `perfect` for now.

```
INSERT INTO notifications (id, text, date, isRead)
VALUES
('7888968F-7817-4386-BAD3-20094A10A0EF', 'this is notification 1', 10000, "true"),
('C161335B-865D-42F8-9468-5942F4579AE5', 'this is notification 2', 20000, "true"),
('527F425A-618A-4C92-9B12-96B781F54819', 'this is notification 3', 30000, "false"),
('76AC88BA-304B-45D4-853B-DE482B1D1916', 'this is notification 4', 40000, "true"),
```